# Category thumbnail at the menu

Tags: magento-1.8, category, thumbnail

I'm Using a mega menu extension for magento. I need to display a thumbnail before the category link in top navigation menu.
So far, I've tried adding 
getThumbnail()  ?>" /> to my menu view file (top.phtml), but It didn't work out.

**My menu view file:**

```
<?php
$menuHelper = $this->helper('olegnaxmegamenu');
if ( $menuHelper->getCfg('general/status') ) :

    $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top', 'megamenu-dropdown');
    ?>
    <?php if ($_menu): ?>
    <div class="nav-container olegnaxmegamenu icons-<?php echo Mage::helper('athlete')->getAppearanceCfg('navigation/sub_nav_icons'); ?>">
        <div class="nav-top-title"><div class="icon"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div><a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Navigation'); ?></a></div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <?php if ($menuHelper->getCfg('additional/home')) : ?>
                <li class="level0 level-top home-block">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></span></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $_menu; ?>
            <?php
            $customBlock = $menuHelper->getCfg('additional/custom_block_id');
            if ( !empty($customBlock) ) {
                $customBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
                    ->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
                    ->load($customBlock);
                if($customBlock->getIsActive()) {
                    echo '
                <li class="level0 level-top parent wide custom-block">
                    <a href="#" class="level-top">
                        <span>'.$customBlock->getTitle().'</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="megamenu-dropdown"><div class="std megamenu-block megamenu-block-top">'.$menuHelper->processCmsBlock($customBlock->getContent()).'</div></div>
                </li>';
                }
            }

            $additionalBlock = $menuHelper->getCfg('additional/additional_block_id');
            if ( !empty($additionalBlock) ) {
                $additionalBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
                    ->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
                    ->load($additionalBlock);
                if($additionalBlock->getIsActive()) {
                    echo $menuHelper->processCmsBlock($additionalBlock->getContent());
                }
            }

            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
<?php endif; //if ( $menuHelper->getCfg('general/status') ) : ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.

Comment: But this question would be the same if I use any other extension, because I need to display a category thumbnail of the category at the main page of the store.

Answer (score 1):

So you can get the thumbnail category

```
<?php
    $thumb = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $thumbnail = $thumb->getThumbnail();
    echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/' . $thumbnail;
?>
```

Now you analyze how best to use in your menu